# Bootstrap 3.0.0 adding extra space on row class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.0.0. I am trying to have a row that spans the whole screen (as opposed to putting it in a 'container' where it will be centred with the rest of the content.

For some reason, when I do this, the row adds an extra space to the end of the page, causing the horizontal scroll bar to appear. The space is approximately 5px.

My code looks like this:

```
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                hello
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Hello
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have not made any modifications at all, and no custom CSS. Basically I want to change the background colour of the row, but I want it to span accross the entire page.

Thanks

Comment: You could easily just add `.container {max-width:100% !important;}`. Just remind me to not visit your site, though... Looking at such sites on a 1440p monitor is just awful... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in BS 3 - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9862?source=cc

You can workaround it using...

```
.row {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Skelly** is right ! with that solution you problem will be **solved**... 
but in case you see that your cols are stick to the left or right and are not **centered** , you can use this code ( with a little change to the Skelly's Code)

```
.row {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
}
```